# Mongodb direct access to ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, objectid

I have a "company" collection like this:

```json
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("58c52a26de0bdd9311000004"), 
  "name" : "ed", 
  "projects" : [ ], 
  "__v" : 0, 
  "users" : [
    ObjectId("58c52a36de0bdd9311000007"),
    ObjectId("58c52a54de0bdd931100000a")
  ]
}
```

I want to get some info from the users; do I have to do a query to get the ObjectID and the another query to each of the users?

Or is there any way to get this info directly from the query to company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **lookup aggregation** to get the data from user collection assuming both the collections are in same database.

> Performs a left outer join to an unsharded collection in the same
>   database to filter in documents from the “joined” collection for
>   processing. The $lookup stage does an equality match between a field
>   from the input documents with a field from the documents of the
>   “joined” collection.

**Basic syntax:-**

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: <collection to join>,
       localField: <field from the input documents>,
       foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
       as: <output array field>
     }
}
```

[MongoDB lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: Function name ?

Comment: populate, 
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

lookup aggregation is working fine btw

Comment: In plain MongoDB, it is lookup. Yes, Populate is the similar API on Mongoose.